# Parsing HTML/Plaintext over HTTP with Objective-C - Text Encoding Issues

Tags: html, objective-c, macos, http, encoding

I am parsing some plaintext/HTML using NSURLConnection like so:

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
//I should find a better way to convert this string
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithCString:[result bytes]];
```

I have tried using both stringWithCString and stringWithUTF8String, and I still get weird HTML formatting crud like this for special characters like `&quot;`or `&#39;`.

I'm sure there is some blindingly obvious better way to decode the text, but I'm really new to ObjC and am a bit lost as to what to Google for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blindingly obvious answer is that to parse HTML, you need an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m

Seems to offer what I am looking for if anyone else comes looking.